# Object complement - good sources

Tags: discussion

Where can I find a list of the verbs that need an object complement, listed according to whether the object complement is a noun or adjective or both?

Comment: https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/object-complement gives the general rule that verbs which take an object complement are generally "those of creating or nominating" - like 'name,' 'choose,' 'elect' etc.